# Format cell as Percentage with NPOI C#

Tags: c#, xls, npoi

I am trying to format a specific XLS cell to the "Percentage" format using NPOI.
I am able to convert it to text using

```
(dataRow.GetCell(17) ?? dataRow.CreateCell(17)).CellStyle.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("Text");
```

But if I try do it with percentage it doesnt work. This is the code I am trying

```
(dataRow.GetCell(17) ?? dataRow.CreateCell(17)).CellStyle.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("Percentage");
```

It will just set that cell as Generic. How would I go about setting it as percentage?
Please keep in mind I want the value e.g 0.05 to be in the cell (not 5%), but with the format as Percentage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. I had to use:

```
(dataRow.GetCell(17) ?? dataRow.CreateCell(17)).CellStyle.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("0.00%");
```

It make it 2dp percentage without the symbol