# How to keep numeric value of Percentage cell NPOI in C#

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

Im trying to format specific XLS cell to the "percentage" format. I read this post: [Format cell as percantage NPOI c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621189/format-cell-as-percentage-with-npoi-c-sharp?fireglass_rsn=true) 
When I use this solution it helps but the problem is that for example: 51.35% keep at excel as 5135.00%.

This is my code:

```
            XSSFCellStyle percentageStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
            percentageStyle.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("0.00%");

            XSSFCell c = (XSSFCell)dataRow.CreateCell(column.Ordinal);
            string val = row[column].ToString();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(val) && val.Contains('%'))
                        {
                            string val2 = val.Trim('%');
                            //Console.WriteLine("percent!" + val);
                            c.SetCellValue(Double.Parse(val2));
                            c.CellStyle = percentageStyle;




                        }
```

Is there any way to change it? I would like that the 'Number' value will be kept with '%'.
Images are attached.[Format cells number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f79xd.png)
[Format cells percentage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHq5U.png)

Comment: In Excel, when a number is displayed as `51.35%`, then the value in the cell is `0.5135`.  The solution to your problem is to divide your value by 100

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, when a number is displayed as 51.35%, then the value in the cell is 0.5135. The solution to your problem is to divide your value by 100

Comment: c.SetCellValue(Double.Parse(val2)/100);